# What are the s-parameters of a rg58 coaxial cable?

Tags: transmission-line, coax, s-parameters

Can a the s-parameters of a rg58 coaxial transmission line be calculated. If yes, what are they?

Comment: s-parameters are an arbitrary choice when it comes to measurement. It doesn't necessarily _have_ to be s-parameters. It could be ABCD-parameters if you wanted to. There are different ways to model a transmission line.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by having the s-parameters of your cable? Do you have the actual physical cable and a network analyzer available so you can just measure them?

Comment: Yes, the S-parameters of RG-58 can be calculated. [This](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273241411_Comparison_of_time-domain_S-parameters_of_RG58_cable_computed_by_Theory_CST_SPICE_DWS) might help you to get more details.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm trying to simulate how a RG58 coax cable interferes with a circuit when used as a testing probe to measure the voltage. To simulate the coax cable I wanted to use a two-port model where I can specify the s parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insertion loss and phase delay (\$S_{21}\$ and \$S_{12}\$) can be roughly calculated from the specifications of the cable.

You can use

$$S_{21} = S_{12} \approx Ae^{-j\theta}$$

where \$A\$ is calculated from the insertion loss (i.e. 10 dB insertion loss would give \$A = \sqrt{0.1}\$), and \$\theta\$ is the electrical length of the cable.

The return loss and phase of the reflection (\$S_{11}\$ and \$S_{22}\$) will depend more on the quality of the connectors you use than on the cable itself.

Comment: Does the 100 pf/meter matter?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, I don't see how it directly affects finding the S-parameters. It does relate to the velocity factor, but hopefully you'll get the velocity factor as a separate spec and not have to work it out from L and C per unit length.